# How do I apply a separate material to an object in a vertex group?

Tags: materials, rigging, vertex-groups

I'm working with Juan Pablo Bouza's beautiful rigged skeleton model for the first time and in the process I'm learning all about working with rigged models for animation in Blender. One thing I would like to do is color some of the bones individually in the model, but **I cannot figure out how to apply a material to just one object in a vertex group**. Is there a way I can do this without messing up the rigging?

In the attached example, I would like to shade the clavicles green instead of blue, but again there doesn't appear to be any obvious way to do this; materials behave as though the entire vertex group is a single object. Any suggestions? Thanks. Blender 3.3.1, Windows 11

[image]

Answer (score 1):

I contacted the creator of the skeleton model, aka "Ferdegund", and he provided me with the solution:

1. Select the object;
2. Add a second material slot;
3. Switch to edit mode and select a vertex in the bone you wish to modify;
4. Press Ctrl+L to select the rest of the connected geometry of the bone;
5. Assign the second material slot to the bone.

Works great!